# Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so, libgstreamer_android.so

Tags: android, crash, native, gstreamer

I got this crash reported on google play developer console from a Galaxy Tab3 Lite 7.0 (goyavewifi), Android 4.4. Any clue what it's about? Any idea to debug it?

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/goyavewifixx/goyavewifi:4.4.4/KTU84P/T113XXU0AQA3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '4'
pid: 5210, tid: 5210, name: m.xxxxxxxx.xxxx >>> com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 0000145a r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 00000000 r6 0000145a r7 0000010c
r8 bec91220 r9 4c5fe9b4 sl 41595890 fp bec911c4
ip 00000000 sp bec90e40 lr 4006f145 pc 4007e038 cpsr 000e0010
d0 736e657327203a00 d1 73657a69735f7200
d2 646c756f68732000 d3 20656220746f6e84
d4 735f68615f747367 d5 65735f726f736e65
d6 7a69735f726f736e d7 696e6965645f7365
d8 bf80000000000000 d9 000000003f800000
d10 400921fb54442d18 d11 3fe0000000000000
d12 4000000000000000 d13 3f0000003f800000
d14 000000003f800000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000005
d18 bfc8f8b83c69a60d d19 3ec71de357b1fe7d
d20 bf29fe0f7ce63c0f d21 3f585a2e8c29082c
d22 bf54a18bed4386b0 d23 3fc5555555555549
d24 bfc921fb5422c458 d25 3dd0b46100000000
d26 0000000000000000 d27 3f8fcf32d797aeef
d28 3fe6a09e667f3bcd d29 402a000000000000
d30 3ff921fb54400000 d31 3dd0b4611a626331
scr 20000013

backtrace:
#00 pc 00022038 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00013141 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02 pc 00013355 /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00012021 /system/lib/libc.so
#04 pc 000218ec /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 018dc10b /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so (g_assertion_message+246)
#06 pc 0108077f /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so (gst_android_hardware_sensor_deinit+178)
#07 pc 01081135 /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so (gst_android_hardware_sensor_init+2440)
#08 pc 0106bd3d /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so
#09 pc 0185a17f /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so
#10 pc 0185ae6d /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so (gst_plugin_register_static+380)
#11 pc 0106ff87 /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so (gst_plugin_androidmedia_register+50)
#12 pc 00290da0 /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so (gst_android_register_static_plugins+304)
#13 pc 002929ec /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so (gst_android_init+1188)
#14 pc 00292ae0 /data/app-lib/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx-1/libgstreamer_android.so
#15 pc 0001dd8c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#16 pc 0004e253 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#17 pc 000271a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#18 pc 0002e150 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#19 pc 0002b7fc /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#20 pc 00060b25 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#21 pc 00068273 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#22 pc 000271a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#23 pc 0002e150 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#24 pc 0002b7fc /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#25 pc 00060b25 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#26 pc 00068ab7 /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

I am using gstreamer 1.0, gstreamer folder included the following: 'arm', 'arm64', 'armv7', 'x86', 'x86_64' folders.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error with GStreamer old version 1.9.2.

Not getting this after I tried recent version 1.12.3.

Can find reported bug here: [Bug 791013](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=791013)